# Slurmctld Purges Files for "Defunct Batch Jobid" on Restart

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, slurm

My slurmctld does not save jobs that are in the queue upon exit (via ctrl+c).

I give it around 1000 jobs, exit (ctrl+c), and upon restart, it states for every job (754 in this example) is defunct and purges the job:

```
slurmctld: Purged files for defunct batch JobId=754
```

Here is the stdout on exit:

```
slurmctld: _job_complete: JobId=22 WEXITSTATUS 0
slurmctld: _job_complete: JobId=22 done
^Cslurmctld: Terminate signal (SIGINT or SIGTERM) received
slurmctld: Saving all slurm state
slurmctld: layouts: all layouts are now unloaded.
```

Here is the stdout on restarting service:

```
jonathan@jonathan-ubuntudesktop:~$ sudo slurmctld -Dcv
slurmctld: slurmctld version 18.08.3 started on cluster jonathan-inspiron-13-7378
slurmctld: Munge cryptographic signature plugin loaded
slurmctld: Consumable Resources (CR) Node Selection plugin loaded with argument 4
slurmctld: preempt/none loaded
slurmctld: ExtSensors NONE plugin loaded
slurmctld: Accounting storage NOT INVOKED plugin loaded
slurmctld: No memory enforcing mechanism configured.
slurmctld: layouts: no layout to initialize
slurmctld: topology NONE plugin loaded
slurmctld: sched: Backfill scheduler plugin loaded
slurmctld: route default plugin loaded
slurmctld: layouts: loading entities/relations information
slurmctld: cons_res: select_p_node_init
slurmctld: cons_res: preparing for 1 partitions
slurmctld: Purged files for defunct batch JobId=1183
slurmctld: Purged files for defunct batch JobId=1023
...
slurmctld: Purged files for defunct batch JobId=1384
slurmctld: Recovered state of 0 reservations
slurmctld: _preserve_plugins: backup_controller not specified
slurmctld: cons_res: select_p_reconfigure
slurmctld: cons_res: select_p_node_init
slurmctld: cons_res: preparing for 1 partitions
slurmctld: Running as primary controller
slurmctld: No parameter for mcs plugin, default values set
slurmctld: mcs: MCSParameters = (null). ondemand set.
slurmctld: job_complete: invalid JobId=986
slurmctld: job_complete: invalid JobId=988
slurmctld: job_complete: invalid JobId=989
slurmctld: job_complete: invalid JobId=987
```

slurm.conf:

```
ControlAddr=192.168.1.2
AuthType=auth/munge
CryptoType=crypto/munge
MaxJobCount=1000000
MpiDefault=none
ProctrackType=proctrack/pgid
ReturnToService=1
SlurmctldPidFile=/home/jonathan/Documents/COMPANYNAME/slurmctl/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/home/jonathan/Documents/COMPANYNAME/slurmctl/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/home/jonathan/Documents/COMPANYNAME/slurmctl/save_state/slurmd
SlurmUser=jonathan
SlurmdUser=jonathan
StateSaveLocation=/home/jonathan/Documents/COMPANYNAME/slurmctl/save_state
SwitchType=switch/none
TaskPlugin=task/none
TaskPluginParam=Sched
InactiveLimit=0
KillWait=30
MinJobAge=300
SlurmctldTimeout=120
SlurmdTimeout=300
Waittime=0
FastSchedule=1
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
SchedulerPort=7321
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
AccountingStoreJobComment=YES
ClusterName=jonathan-Inspiron-13-7378
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmdDebug=3
NodeName=jonathan-Inspiron-13-7378 NodeAddr=192.168.1.4 CPUs=4 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=Grid0 Nodes=jonathan-Inspiron-13-7378 Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

"/home/jonathan/Documents/COMPANYNAME/slurmctl/save_state"'s owner is jonathan:jonathan and has 750 permissions.

Slurm-18.08.3 install was just the basic ./configure, make, and make install.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for the help, it is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

And I am an idiot. I followed the command from the tutorial blindly instead of reading what each flag does.

The issue was caused by -c flag, so instead of "slurmctld -Dcv" I needed to run "slurmctld -Dv" on the rare chance anyone else has this issue...

Cheers!